# jquery check or wait for the variable has value and then continue

Tags: jquery, promise, wait

Can I wait for or check for a variable having a value before to continue a function?

```
var someVar = false;

$('.someEl').animate({'marginLeft': 100}, 500, function () {
    // animating complete
    someVar = true;
});

function someFunction () {
    // watch someVar to be true and then run the code in this function
}

someFunction();
```

Comment: It's likely that this is the wrong route to solve whatever the actual problem is. Why can't you call the function in the `.animate()` callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Straight Forward:

```
var someVar = false;

$('.someEl').animate({'marginLeft': 100}, 500, function () {
    // animating complete
    someVar = true;
    someFunction();
});

function someFunction () {
    // watch someVar to be true and then run the code in this function
}
```

With kind of a watch:

```
var someVar = false;

$('.someEl').animate({'marginLeft': 100}, 500, function () {
    // animating complete
    someVar = true;
});

function someFunction () {
    if (someVar) { do.. }
    else setTimeout(function() { someFunction(); }, 1);
}
```